# Install Symfony on a server with no internet connection

Tags: php, symfony, xampp

Is it possible to install symfony and all it's components on a server without internet connection?

I hope that I can download the required files and copy and install on the server.

I intend to create an application to run on the intranet of the company. I'm already using XAMPP and the PHP version is 5.3.8.

Thanks

Comment: Can you install it locally and upload via FTP? If so, then yes.

Comment: I have access through the windows network. Can I just install it on a local PC and copy all the files to the remote server? (It's a windows server btw)

Comment: Much easier would be to simply establish a temporary internet connection for the setup, for example by means of an ssh tunnel and to access that via proxy settings.

Comment: I don't have administrator privileges on the remote machine, I just have access to the xampp folder through the windows network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can install symfony on a server with no internet connection. What you would need to do is have your project up and running with all the vendors already installed and then you would copy the project into your network share.

In other words:

1. Go to a computer with an internet connection
2. Run `composer install` so it will download all necessary dependencies
3. Copy the project to the machine with no internet access.
4. Make sure to clean your cache folder on the server (i.e `rm -rf app/cache/{prod,dev,test}`)

And everything should be working just fine. I've done this in multiple cases when `composer` was not available on a shared hosting, which is pretty much the same as "not having internet". :)

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll try that.

Comment: Let me know if it works and in case everything is ok, please upvote and accept this answer :)